# AWS RDS modify snapshot schema tables as NULLS

Tags: database, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, database-migration

I have a simple case where I have an AWS RDS snapshot and I want to modify the data inside that particular snapshot and share the database (snapshot). i.e. I want to modify few columns as nulls so that the client cannot see those columns.
I was looking into the API documentation but couldn't find the correct way of doing this. I looked into documentation [Modifying an Amazon RDS DB instance](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Overview.DBInstance.Modifying.html) and [ModifyDBSnapshot](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/APIReference/API_ModifyDBSnapshot.html) etc but these modifications are meant for modifications in database engine and configuration settings.

Need expert opinion on how to accomplish this task in an optimal way. TIA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You **can't modify the content of DB on the snapshot**. You have to:

1. restore your snapshot to a new DB instance first,
2. remove/modify the columns you want by connecting to your DB as you would normally do, and
3. create new snapshot of it.

Then you can copy/share the modified snapshot.